# JMETER: Sending Files with Webservice Request

Tags: web-services, jmeter, sendfile

I need to send files with a webservice request. But I don't know how to specify the file int the WebService(SOAP) Request.

How can I do that? Or is it possible to use the HTTP Request?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter provides at least 2 options on how you can pass a file to a sampler, function or whatever.

**Option 1:** [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function. Just put it into your "SOAP/XML-RPC Data" textarea as follows:

```
${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file.xml,,)}
```

**Option 2:** Another, more flexible option is reading file via scripting extension (i.e. if XML file encoding is different from your current system encoding and becomes corrupted).

Add a [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of your SOAP/XML-RPC Request with code like:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

String file = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/path/to/your/file.xml"),"UTF-8");
vars.put("file",new String(Base64.encodeBase64(file.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
```

It'll read contents of /path/to/your/file.xml file using UTF-8 charset and store result on "file" JMeter Variable.

Just put `${file}` or `${__V(file)}` into "SOAP/XML-RPC Data" text area. That's it.

See [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on JMeter extension by scripting.

You can use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to get full information on request/response.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But The file hast du be encoded with Base64? How can I do this?

Comment: I've updated Beanshell code snippet to encode file into Base64.

Comment: This looks like the answer i'm looking for. Does it also works with pictures or binary data (PDF, compressed files, etc)?

Comment: The use case looks weird but the code above will read ANY file into string, encode it into Base64 and store it to `file` variable.